# Private Azure Kubernetes cluster scale up problem

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-load-balancer

I have private AKS cluster with internal LoabBalancer. When I try to start-stop or scale up/down cluster it always infinitely starts on node creation step without success.

Same AKS cluster with public LoadBalancer with outbound rules or without any LoadBalancer is able to start (scale up). I my architecture I want to avoid outbound Internet access, or at least allow only Azure related endpoints.

Does someone knows how can it be solved? Or what is the problem in my original setup?

Comment: I guess some issues with the private ip allocation configuration

Comment: @OLA Can you please mention the exact error as screenshot which you are getting to understand more about the issue